# Convert CRC16 C# code to Java CRC16

Tags: java, c#, crc16

I have a C# code that calculates CRC16 on my byte array:

```
    public static byte[] CalculateCRC(byte[] data)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        ushort temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            ushort value = (ushort)data[i];

            temp = (ushort)(value ^ (ushort)(crc >> 8));
            temp = (ushort)(temp ^ (ushort)(temp >> 4));
            temp = (ushort)(temp ^ (ushort)(temp >> 2));
            temp = (ushort)(temp ^ (ushort)(temp >> 1));

            crc = (ushort)((ushort)(crc << 8) ^ (ushort)(temp << 15) ^ (ushort)(temp << 2) ^ temp);
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(CRC >> 8), (byte)CRC };
        return bytes;
    }
```

Now, I have to duplicate the exact same logic in Java. But, the below code I wrote is not giving me the expected result.

```
public static byte[] calculateCrc16(byte[] data)
{
    char crc = 0x0000;
    char temp;
    byte[] crcBytes;

    for(int i = 0; i<data.length;++i)
    {
        char value = (char) (data[i] & 0xFF);

        temp = (char)(value ^ (char) (crc >> 8));
        temp = (char)(temp ^ (char) (temp >> 4));
        temp = (char)(temp ^ (char) (temp >> 2));
        temp = (char)(temp ^ (char) (temp >> 1));

        crc = (char) ((char)(crc << 8)^ (char)(temp <<15) ^ (char)(temp << 2) ^ temp);
    } //END of for loop

    crcBytes = new byte[]{(byte)((crc<<8) & 0x00FF), (byte)(crc & 0x00FF)};
    return crcBytes;
}
```

I am not able to figure out what logic is wrong with my java code. Any help would be appreciated.

The test data is the following byte array

```
{
48, 48, 56, 50, 126, 49, 126, 53, 53, 53, 126, 53, 126, 54, 48, 126,
195, 120, 202, 249, 35, 221, 44, 162, 7, 191, 207, 64, 31, 144, 88,
62, 201, 51, 191, 234, 82, 62, 226, 1, 69, 186, 192, 26, 171, 197, 229,
247, 180, 155, 255, 228, 86, 213, 255, 254, 215, 89, 53, 96, 186, 49, 135,
185, 0, 19, 103, 168, 44, 8, 203, 154, 150, 237, 234, 176, 110, 113, 154
}
```

should return {86, 216}

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Java type byte has range of -128,...,127. With your test data, I can't even compile.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle take above sample as int array and convert it into byte array using (byte) intValue.

Comment: I don't get that result with the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

A `ushort` is 16 bits, whereas a `char` is 8 bits. So it is impossible for your Java version to have the same intermediate values. Use `int`, which can store 16-bit values just fine.

If you use int, then you will need to truncate the result to 16 bits for each loop, so put in a `crc &= 0xffff;` before the end of the loop.